# Integrability of constant function over open set

Tags: integration, measure-theory

> It  is tempting to think,  for instance, that any bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n} $ is
> rectifiable

whereby a rectifiable  set $S$ is defined as a set for which
\begin{align*}
\int_{S}^{} 1 
\end{align*}
exists. Why is it tempting to think this holds? Isn't already the set
$$A=\{(x, y)\mid x^{2}+y^{2}<1\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2} $$ not rectifiable, since the measure of
its boundary is nonzero, or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: Why is the boundary not of measure zero?

Comment: It's boundary is the circle $C(1)$ of radius $1$, which can be shown to have Lebesgue measure $0$. To show this, note that $B(0, 1 + \varepsilon) \setminus B(0, 1 - \varepsilon) \searrow C(1)$ as $\varepsilon \searrow 0$.

Comment: The open ball has boundary of $n$-dimensional measure zero as explained above. The reason why the statement is "tempting" is because our "prototype" (in the sense that they are typically our starting point for generating the usual topology) bounded open sets are things like open rectangles, open balls/ open ellipsoids etc all of which are rectifiable. So because most of the sets we can easily draw/visualize are finite unions of such nice sets (and hence rectifiable), it is tempting to make the leap and conclude that every bounded open set is rectifiable. Unfortunately, this is false.

Comment: thanks a lot for the comments, it seems that I didn't properly read the definition of measure!